# How to output a set containing a Struct Location for

Tags: c++, set, output, a-star

This is the start of a basic A* algorithm, how do I output whats inside the set? What i have so far doesn't work and I get this error

"Error  1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Location' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

```
void astar(Location Start_Location, Location End_Location)
{
    Location Current_Location;
    Current_Location.g = 1;
    Start_Location.g = 1;

    int position = 0;
    bool found = false;

    Start_Location.g = 0;
    Start_Location.h = (abs(Start.x - End.x) + abs(Start.y - End.y));
    Start_Location.f = Start_Location.g + Start_Location.h;

    std::set<Location> myset;
    std::set<Location>::iterator it;

    myset.insert(it, Start_Location);

    current_Coord.x = End.x;
    current_Coord.y = End.y;

    /*while (!myset.empty())
    {*/
        Current_Location.h = (abs(current_Coord.x - End.x) + abs(current_Coord.y - End.y));
        Current_Location.f = Current_Location.g + Current_Location.h;

        //calculates f around current node
            Current_Location.h = (abs(current_Coord.x - End.x) + abs((current_Coord.y - 1) - End.y));
            Current_Location.f = Current_Location.g + Current_Location.h;
            myset.insert(it, Current_Location);

            Current_Location.h = (abs(current_Coord.x - End.x) + abs((current_Coord.y + 1) - End.y));
            Current_Location.f = Current_Location.g + Current_Location.h;
            myset.insert(it, Current_Location);

            Current_Location.h = (abs((current_Coord.x - 1) - End.x) + abs(current_Coord.y - End.y));
            Current_Location.f = Current_Location.g + Current_Location.h;
            myset.insert(it, Current_Location);

            Current_Location.h = (abs((current_Coord.x + 1) - End.x) + abs(current_Coord.y - End.y));
            Current_Location.f = Current_Location.g + Current_Location.h;
            myset.insert(it, Current_Location);


            for (it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
            {
                cout << ' ' << *it;
            }

    //}
}
```

Comment: You need to overload the extraction operator (<<) for type `Location`.

Comment: how exactly would i do that?

Comment: @NiallClarke Show how Location is defined and how you are going to output it

Comment: this is how it is defined
struct Location
{
 int f, g, h;
};

Comment: how i plan on outputting it

for (it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
            {
                cout << ' ' << *it;
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Error 1 error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'const Location' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)"

If you read the error carefully you will see that you are trying to pass an object of type 'const Location' as a parameter to the extraction operator which you do inside your for loop.

```
for (it = myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << ' ' << *it;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler cannot find any overload (or acceptable conversion) that accepts that type. This means that you most definitely have not defined it.

**Solution.**

The solution is simple, you must define an appropriate overload for the << operator. The following example is one of many ways you can do this.

```
struct Location
{
    int f, g, h;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Location& l)
    {
        os << l.f << ' ' << l.g << ' ' << l.h;
        return os;
    }
};
```